# error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 16

Tags: python, binary, zip, unpack

The following code gives me an error:

> unpack requires a bytes object of length 16

https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/stdlib2.html#brief-tour-of-the-standard-library-part-ii

11.3. Working with Binary Data Record Layouts

```
import struct

with open('myfile.zip', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

start = 0
for i in range(3):                      # show the first 3 file headers
    start += 14
    fields = struct.unpack('<IIIHH', data[start:start+16])
    crc32, comp_size, uncomp_size, filenamesize, extra_size = fields

    start += 16
    filename = data[start:start+filenamesize]
    start += filenamesize
    extra = data[start:start+extra_size]
    print(filename, hex(crc32), comp_size, uncomp_size)

    start += extra_size + comp_size     # skip to the next header
```

I created 'myfile.txt' like this (this may be wrong, but what else could I do?):

```
0001000100010001
0001000100010001
0001000100010001
0001000100010001
0001000100010001
0001000100010001
0001000100010001
0001000100010001
0001000100010001
0001000100010001
0001000100010001
0001000100010001
0001000100010001
0001000100010001
0001000100010001
0001000100010001
0001000100010001
0001000100010001
0001000100010001
0001000100010001
```

... and zipped it as 'myfile.zip'.

The result is:

```
b'myfile.txt' 0xb52979e4 42 6818
b'' 0x79e448ab 2798889 446824448
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-d2e06ac7c75b> in <module>()
      7 for i in range(3):                      # show the first 3 file headers
      8     start += 14
----> 9     fields = struct.unpack('<IIIHH', data[start:start+16])
     10     crc32, comp_size, uncomp_size, filenamesize, extra_size = fields
     11

error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 16
```

I know 'IIIHH' means 4 bytes + 4 bytes + 4 bytes + 2 bytes + 2bytes = 16 bytes. But, I don't know the structure of a ZIP file. Does the same code work for you guys? How can I make this work?

Comment: What is the content of `myfile.txt` exactly? Is it 40 bytes which you've encoded in binary and pasted in your question or is it 360/340 bytes of plain ASCII text (exact size depends on newlines style)

Comment: It is 340 bytes of plain ASCII text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the code attempts to display the metadata about the first *three* files in the zip, but your zip only contains a single file.

If you change

```
for i in range(3):                      # show the first 3 file headers
```

to

```
for i in range(1):
```

it'll work.

Comment: Actually, it's not entirely correct to talk about first three files in the zip, because files can be deleted and overwritten in zip by appending to the end of archive. The code reads first three local file headers in assumption that they follow each other without any gaps/padding.

Comment: Yes, it works! Firstly, I tried 
for i in range(1):
The result is:
b'myfile.txt' 0xb52979e4 42 6818 (without any error)

Then, I tried
for i in range(3): 
with 'myfile.zip' containing three files.
The result is:
b'myfile1.txt' 0x61980efa 15 340
b'myfile2.txt' 0x61980efa 15 340
b'myfile3.txt' 0x61980efa 15 340 (without any error)
I will have to learn more about zip, but for now this is way too enough.
Thank you very much, Rawing! (Thank you, yeputons, too!)